# Easier to root, Samsung or HTC?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3, htc-one, verizon

I have had an HTC One M7 for a while, and I have wanted to root it but am afraid to brick it (I'm on Verizon). So I bought a Samsung galaxy s3. I would like to know which one is easier to root. I plan to use Cyanogenmod for either one. It is easy for me to change which phone is on the network, I just move the SIM card. They are both verizon phones. I dont really know what unlocking the bootloader is, so i cant say if either of them have the bootloader unlocked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsungs are generally easier to root in my experience. The samsungs do not require s-off compared to htc's and thus, it is much harder to brick. The popular models like the s3 usually get a lot of support from the developer community compared to something like the HTC m7.

Here are some guides:

[S3 Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2235366)

[HTC m7 Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-htc-one/general/root-root-method-bl-unlock-5-0-x-ota-t3122099)